# A nice form for this Beta-like integral $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^\alpha(n t) \cos^\beta(t)dt$?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I was differentiating a completely different integral when I came across
$$I(\alpha,\beta,n)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^\alpha(nt) \cos^\beta(t)dt.$$

Evidently, $I(\alpha, \beta,1)= \frac{1}{2} B \left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2},\frac{\beta+1}{2} \right)$, where $B$ is the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
Is this function expressible in terms of other widely-known functions? I doubt Chebyschev Polynomials will help here.

Comment: Maple fails with it in the general case. However, Maple finds the integral for concrete values of the parameters, e. g. $$int(sin(3*t)^4*cos(t)^{1/2}, t = 0 .. (1/2)*Pi) $$ produces $$ -{\frac {1964}{5525}}\,\sqrt {2}{\it EllipticK} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2}
 \right) +{\frac {3928}{5525}}\,\sqrt {2}{\it EllipticE} \left( 1/2\,
\sqrt {2} \right) .
$$

Comment: It is not an outstanding idea, but we can write $\sin(nt)$ as $\frac{e^{nit}-e^{-nit}}{2i}$, $\cos t$ as $\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$, compute the powers in terms of binomials, then integrate all the complex exponentials arising from the Cauchy product. This, for sure, gives an expression for $I(\alpha,\beta,n)$ as a sum of products of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Chebyschev Polynomials are only helpful for rational number $n$ .

Comment: @HarryPeter Indeed that comment seems silly now, my doubts were certainly correct then.